# How to run my php file from mac terminal

Tags: php

Sorry if this is a very novice question - I am a novice - but, I have no clue how to run my php file from the terminal.

I type in the mac terminal something like this: php test.php (where test.php is the file i'm trying to run)
Then, I get this: Could not open input file: test.php

I think I'm having this problem because I didn't change the directory (not sure how to do that either).

Comment: This isn't really on topic here on Stack Overflow, but you will need to change into the correct directory with the `cd` command, as in `cd dir/to/file/test.php` or absolute path `cd /Users/you/yourcode/test.php`

Comment: I'd recommend searching for some basic beginner Bash tutorials (Bash is the Unix shell you're using)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski you mean `cd dir/to/file/`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In order to change the directory, you must type cd and then the file path name

If you find the file in Finder, and hold the file, and drag it to the mac terminal window, it will place the entire path file....so just type cd, then drag file to get path

- DO NOT FORGET TO REMOVE THE FILE NAME ON THE END OF THE PATH

and that will take you to the directory of the file..

after that, just type `php test.php`, and that should work

Hope this helps!

Comment: A quicker way to do this would be to write `php`, then drag the path without deleting the file name. For example `php /this/is/a/path/script.php`

Comment: yeah, being a one line command would definitely make it quicker. Didn't realize that.

Comment: @WenqinYe If you're not sure where you are in the directory tree, type `pwd` for "print working directory"

Answer (score 0):

Start a terminal window.
at the prompt enter 'emacs hi.php'
in the emacs editor enter a line that reads print "hi world"
enter cntl x-s to save your file
then enter cntl-z to exit to the terminal window
then type php hi.php
you should see "hi world" displayed in the terminal window.
then type fg to return to the emacs editor.